# How to use std::vector<std::tuple<A,B>> to manage memory (resize, reserve,...), but actually keeping the As before the Bs, contiguously

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl, data-oriented-design

I'm working on an entity-component system (ECS), inspired on [Bitsquid's blog series](http://bitsquid.blogspot.co.uk/2014/08/building-data-oriented-entity-system.html). My ECS is composed of two main classes: System (responsible for creating/destroying entities) and Property (responsible for storing a std::vector of a component, for a given System).

When an Entity is created/destroyed, the System triggers some signals to keep the Property instances aware of the state-change on Systems, in order to keep the data contiguous and well-mapped.

Follow below a simple example of a system of cars, and each car has two properties: point2d position, std::string name.

```
System<Car> cars;
Property<Car, point2d> positions(cars);
Property<Car, std::string> names(cars);
auto car0 = cars.add();
auto car1 = cars.add();
positions[car0] = {0.0, 0.0};
names[car0]     = "Car 0";
positions[car1] = {1.0, 2.0};
names[car1]     = "Car 1";
```

This way I can keep the data in separate "arrays".

Let's suppose I want to add 1000 Entities. I could do it calling `std::vector::reserve(1000)` on all of the properties, and then doing 1000 `push_back` on each one of them.

I've identified a problem on such approach: I would need 1+N `reserves`, if I have N properties. I was wondering if I could use a `std::vector<tuple<point2d, std::string>>` for handling the memory allocations, but manage the data pretending (reinterpret cast?) I have the all the `point2d` stored contiguously, followed by the strings.

This way I could take advantage of `std::vector` api for saving notifying/reserve/resizing operations. Although I'd have to adapt the accessing methods (like vector::at, operator[], begin, end).

Do you have any ideas on how to achieve that? Or any alternate suggestions if you think this is not a good idea?

Comment: what's wrong with the `std::get`?

Comment: I don't know. What is wrong? :)

Comment: let's start with obvious - `std::get` is a standard way of getting reference to given `std::tuple` field... If you'd like to use `std::tuple` I don't see any reason why you would want to use any other approach than `std::get` to access the tuple content...

Comment: I see. Maybe I wasn't clear enough. Actually I would like to use an `std::vector<std::tuple<A, B>>` to provide the `resize` and `reserve` methods, but I want to manage the data pretending they are stored as As followed by Bs. This would be interesting for me, because I would save reserve/resize calls comparing to having two separate `std::vector<A>` and `std::vector<B>`.

Comment: why would you want to keep closely related data in separate arrays?

Comment: How exactly do you plan to "pretend they are stored as As followed by Bs"? Can you show the kind of code you expect to be able to write in light of this pretense, that you can't write otherwise?

Comment: Well, I just want to store As contiguously, followed by Bs. The relationship between these data is that their sizes are always equal. But I want to be able to iterate over either the As or the Bs, without polluting my cache with unwanted data. The original idea of using vector<tuple<A,B>> was to have "automatic" management of the size of the container, even if I want to manage the raw bytes. Btw, I'm kind of achieving what I'm expecting here:https://github.com/csguth/Entity/blob/master/Entity/TupleVectorTest.cpp. Crits are welcome.

Comment: @RichardHodges: The entire point of "entity-component system" and "Data-Oriented Entity System" is to keep data grouped by type. You can get some slight data density wins there.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible, at least not with `std::tuple`. You can consider `tuple` as a simple `struct` with members from `tuple`s template args. This means they'll be aligned in memory each after another.

Instead all your managers can implement an interface that allows resizing (reserving) and you can register all your managers in er.. `ManagerOfManagers` that will resize all of them in a loop

Answer (score 1):

I've (almost) finished my SoA implementation using `std::vector` as underlying data structure.

Suppose we want to create a SoA for types `<int, double, char>`. Instead of creating three vectors, one for each type, `TupleVector<int, double, char>` class creates a single `std::vector`. For data accessing/reserve/resize it plays with reinterpret cast, offset and tuple size calculations.

I just created a simple benchmark code that calls `.resize(.size()+1)` 10.000.000 times and my SoA implementation appears to be +-4x faster than using separate `std::vectors`.

Here you can see the benchmark code:
https://github.com/csguth/Entity/blob/development/src/Test/TupleVectorBenchmark.cpp

Although this implementation still needs some iterator capabilities (trivial) and more benchmarking.

Hope this can be useful to someone!!

Answer (score 1):

Seems that there is no simple way to make `std::vector<T>` operate on some data other than it's own array of Ts. So, your options include searching for third party SoA (Stucture of Arrays) library, or making your own.

This might be a starting point for a SoA class, that mimics `std::vector`'s interface:

```
// This snippet uses C++14 features
#include <functional>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

template <typename F, typename... Ts, std::size_t... Is>
void tuple_for_each(std::tuple<Ts...>& tuple, F f, std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
    using expander = int[];
    (void)expander{0, ((void)f(std::get<Is>(tuple)), 0)...};
}

template <typename F, typename... Ts>
void tuple_for_each(std::tuple<Ts...>& tuple, F f) {
    tuple_for_each(tuple, f, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts)>());
}

// Missing in this example:
// - full support for std::vector's interface (iterators, exception safety guarantees, etc.);
// - access to individual homogeneous vectors;
// - lots of other things.

template <typename T, typename... Ts>
class soa_vector {
    std::tuple<std::vector<T>, std::vector<Ts>...> data_;

    template <std::size_t>
    void push_back_impl() const {}

    template <std::size_t position, typename Value, typename... Values>
    void push_back_impl(Value&& value, Values&&... values) {
        std::get<position>(data_).push_back(std::forward<Value>(value));
        push_back_impl<position + 1, Values...>(std::forward<Values>(values)...);
    }

    template<std::size_t... Is>
    std::tuple<std::add_lvalue_reference_t<T>, std::add_lvalue_reference_t<Ts>...>
    tuple_at(std::size_t position, std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
        return std::make_tuple(std::ref(std::get<Is>(data_)[position])...);
    }

public:    
    template <typename... Values>
    std::enable_if_t<sizeof...(Values) == sizeof...(Ts) + 1, void>
    push_back(Values&&... values) {
        push_back_impl<0, Values...>(std::forward<Values>(values)...);
    }

    void reserve(std::size_t new_capacity) {
        tuple_for_each(data_, [new_capacity](auto& vec) { vec.reserve(new_capacity); });
    }

    std::size_t size() const { return std::get<0>(data_).size(); }

    std::tuple<std::add_lvalue_reference_t<T>, std::add_lvalue_reference_t<Ts>...>
    operator[](std::size_t position) {
        return tuple_at(position, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts) + 1>());
    }
};
```

[<kbd>On Coliru</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dd20240869dbaf65)